# C# : SQL reader.read() determine if connection is interrupted

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datatable that shows the data of a textfile. This datatable will then be used to update a row/rows that matches the an ID in the Database with the ID inside the text. A scenario will be like:

Textfile:

## [TxtId][name][address]

1   john   place123 
2   doe    place456 
3   jes    place789

Sql table:

## [Id][TxtId][items]

1     1     bag 
2     1     pencil 
3     1     pen 
4     2     bag

I want to know that in this row line, if the id from textfile matches the txtid in the table. It will execute an update, at the same time, it will generate a log file in each line of row in the reader to see if the data really updates,then it will increment a counter in update counter given that all of the matches of that id are updated to the database, error count will be incremented otherwise. Now, my problem is how will
I know if **while(reader.read())** is reading the last row so that i will know that id 1 in text file is fully updated to the database

Answer (score 0):

You process is a standard ETL process.  ETL stands for Extract, Transform, Load -- which is what you are doing here.  There is a lot of information on ETLs and how to do them on the internet, I recommend you read up on it if you can.

For your case, the standard process would be to have a special table called a "staging table" where you load the new data into as first step.  Then you can use that table in your DB to do your compares and updates.  The business rules for updating the "production table" from the "staging table" are relatively simple compared with writing a C# program that read and write form two different locations (a text file and an DB table) as it attempts to execute the business rules.

Your business rules are not 100% clear to me but it looks like if you had a staging table they could be accomplished with one UPDATE query in SQL (maybe two if you have to do some deletes too.)  I think you can already see that one query is much simpler than the logic you are trying to figure out to make it work without a staging table.

So that is my recommended approach here -- make a staging table and then do your compares and updates using that table.